# Access camera functionality in Android webview?

Tags: android, webview, camera, android-webview, android-camera

I'm building a Native-Android/WebView-App thats code is hosted on a remote server (in HTML and Javascript).

The Web App has a function that launches the phone's camera via a HTML form, input request:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="image" type="file" accept="image/*" capture/>
</form>
```

This feature works perfectly well in the standard Android web browser but not in the Native App WebView browser.

I have enabled the following permissions in the Native app manifest but still can't get the camera to launch:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Failing getting this feature to work, I would accept being able to access the camera roll instead so that a user could simply select a photo they have already taken but I would rather launch the camera the way it does in the standard web browser.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

While accessing Camera from Webview, it asks for permissions and we can grant them by overriding the onPermissionRequest. Also make sure to take care of runtime permissions.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });
```

Also, make sure this property is disabled

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use Javascript interface to launch camera.

Or

You can use [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) Framework.

Comment: I don't wont the overhead of using cordova. Looked quickly into a Javascript interface but can't find a working demo. I tried a few but they don't work in WebView.

Comment: Have a look at this link developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript

Comment: Can you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695705/enable-input-file-camera-on-android-webview

Comment: Out of context. This is a pure webview solution.